# Touchpad sometimes lagging in scrolling

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

i'm using **ubuntu 20.04.1** and i'm facing this problem when i scroll in any application sometimes it works perfectly and sometimes lagging and i don't know why .

i try to find out solution , but i'm new in ubuntu and i don't know why this happend

this what i got from `xinput --list`

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ EasyCamera: EasyCamera                    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and when i list `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` with `xinput list 13`

```
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 8 classes:
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 12
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" None None None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: 1272.000000 - 5670.000000
          Resolution: 43000 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: 1108.000000 - 4744.000000
          Resolution: 66000 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Horiz Scroll
          Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Rel Vert Scroll
          Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 4:
          Label: Abs MT Pressure
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 2 (horizontal)
          increment: 114.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 3
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: -114.000000
          flags: 0x0
```

this what i got.

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04.1. It happens when I do not use the touchpad for a few seconds. For instance, if I don't use it for 30 seconds and then I try to scroll as my first command. If the first command is to move the pointer, then it works fine.